# Make framework compatible for different Xcode versions

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have a specific scenario I am trying to overcome and have yet to find a solution (if one exists) to my problem.

I am building a framework that can be used inside of other applications. This framework contains static libraries.

Now, inside my framework, if I want to add classes that use APIs from Xcode12, I would also want my framework to be able to compile in Xcode11.

This could obviously lead to compilation issues as I have no control of my framework inside other applications and as my framework will already be turned into a binary file (.a). Adding any build script to the frameworks' build phases won't be relevant.

I have been trying to look for similar scenarios or solutions for this problem, but have yet to find anything substantial.

Is there any way to overcome this or am I trying to do something that is impossible?